# Получить значение

Tags: java, list

Помогите в решении проблемы. Есть класс

```
public class RatesModel {

  private List<Valute> articleList;


  public List<Valute> getArticleList() {
      return articleList;
  }

  public void setArticleList(List<Valute> articleList) {
      this.articleList = articleList;
  }
```

И класс

```
public class Valute {

   private String id;

   private String charCode;

   private String nominal;

   private String name;

   private String value;

   public String getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getCharCode() {
       return charCode;
   }

   public void setCharCode(String charCode) {
       this.charCode = charCode;
   }

   public String getNominal() {
       return nominal;
   }

   public void setNominal(String nominal) {
       this.nominal = nominal;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getValue() {
       return value;
   }

   public void setValue(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
```

Подскажите как получит все значения getName() из класса Valute через RatesModel.getArticleList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> names = rates.
  getArticleList().
  stream().
  map(i -> i.getName()).
  collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> Подскажите как это сделать через for

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Valute> articles = rates.getArticleList();
for (int i = 0; i < articles.size(); i++) {
  names.add(articles.get(i).getName());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Этот вариант подошел. Для саморазвития вопрос. А можно обойтись без stream()? Какими-нибудь старыми методами.

Comment: @АлександрАртёмов Можно. Старым добрым циклом `for`.

Comment: Я из начинающих. Подскажите как это сделать через for,

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно.